# Importing data involving Junction object and self lookups into a different sandbox using Salesforce DX

Tags: apex, salesforcedx

I have 3 custom objects Object A, Object B and Object C. In which Object A and B are both parents to Object C which means Object C is a junction object. Also Object A has a self Lookup to itself. My requirement is to import records of all 3 objects A, B and C at same time into a different sandbox. For this I am trying to use the SFDX command `sfdx force:data:tree:export` and `sfdx force:data:tree:import`. What should be the query that I can use to import data all at once from all 3 objects into the target org which means after `sfdx force:data:tree:import` command all records of Object A, B and C should be imported along with Object A records with self lookups populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at [SFDX Data Loader plugin](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SFDX-Data-Move-Utility), it is able to manage such cases with circular dependencies

The documentation example seems to match your use case

[image]

https://help.sfdmu.com/plugin-basics/basic-usage/minimal-configuration

If you want sfdx export/import commands to be automatically generated, you can also use **Data import/export** menu of [VsCode SFDX Hardis](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NicolasVuillamy.vscode-sfdx-hardis#data-import-export)